# Unidentified Python indent error

Tags: python

Im getting `IndentationError: expected an indented block` in Sublime2 and PyCharm, and I have no idea where the bug lives.  Im newish to developing in python.  It's getting called on the line beginning with `render`

```
    print(get_title(1))

    render = web.template.render('templates/')

    #maps URLs to classes
    urls = (
        '/commits', 'commits',
        '/new', 'new',
        '/login', 'login'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you mixed tabs and spaces. Best, use only spaces.

Comment: suggestion on how exactly to do that?  ive combed through the code and ensured that there are no tabs or spaces.

Comment: You have combed through the code to ensure there is no tabs or spaces? Well there has to be at least one of those two things.

Answer (score 0):

1. CTRL + F
2. Press TAB
3. Click find all
4. Press space 4 times

Comment: @marsh SublimeText does this, the editor OP was using.